# How do i seperate a String so that "cat!" will be "cat !"

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I believe this program will work for most instances except one. I added spaces in indexOF() so words like cathrine and dogsuit lammas Would all be accepted as non profane. The only problem i see is if the user starts the line with cat/dog/llama. CAT!  Would show up as non profane because there is no space at the start and there is no space afterwards, is there a String command to spread things out or am i completely on the wrong path?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProfanityFilter 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

   System.out.println (" welcome to the Profanity filter billboard service ");
   System.out.println (" please enter  a potential sign that contains the words \"cat\", \"dog\" or \"llama\"" );

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

   String s1 = keyboard.nextLine();

   s1 = s1.toLowerCase();

   if (s1.indexOf(" cat ")!=-1 || s1.indexOf(" dog ") !=-1 || s1.indexOf(" llama ")!=-1)

         System.out.println ("Profanity is in your Billboard");
   else
        System.out.println ("There is no profanity in your Billboard");

 }
}
```

Comment: I messed up in the title... so cat! will be cat !

Comment: You can edit your posts with the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7464206/edit) link just below the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex to the rescue!

```
if (s1.matches("^.*\\b(cat|dog|llama)\\b.*$"))
```

Some explanation:

- `\b` means word boundary
- `(a|b|c)` means "a or b or c"

You could construct this from an array:

```
String[] badWords = {"cat", "dog", "llama"};
String regex = "^.*\\b(" + 
    Arrays.toString(badWords).replace(", ", "|").replace("[", "").replace("]", "") + 
    ")\\b.*$";
```

Comment: use precompiled `java.util.regex.Pattern`s for efficiency ;)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, and `\b`, which means word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows that way it will work for "cat" and "horse, cat, and goat" as well.

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(s1, @"\b(?:cat|dog|llama)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    System.out.println("Profanity is in your Billboard");
```

Okay, I thought it was C#, but something similar exists in Java.